# Images in Adobe Flex

Tags: apache-flex, image, mobile, renderer, flex4.5

Im very new to Adobe Flex/Actionscript and am trying to create a person search application. So far I have my results showing as a horizontal list, but Id like to include an image above each name as my wonderful paint skills show:

[image]

```
/* listOfPeople is a list of arrays with a["name"] a["sex"] a["dob"] and 
   a["image"] which is just a URI to the image */

<s:List width="100%" height="100%" id="results" dataProvider="{listOfPeople}" change="clickPerson(event)">
    <s:itemRenderer>
        <fx:Component>
            <s:MobileIconItemRenderer
                iconField="{data.image}"
                 iconHeight="100" iconWidth="100"
                label="{data.name} - {data.sex}"
                messageField="dob"/>
        </fx:Component>

    </s:itemRenderer>
    <s:layout>
        <s:HorizontalLayout paddingBottom="100" gap="6" paddingTop="100" paddingLeft="0"
            paddingRight="0"
            requestedColumnCount="-1"
            variableColumnWidth="true"
            verticalAlign="bottom"
            /> 
    </s:layout>
</s:List>
```

Any ideas? The iconField doesn't seem to show at all... even when using the full path with correct backslashes

Cheers
Phil

EDIT:

The image displays fine on the PersonDetails screen, when the person is clicked upon:

```
<s:HGroup verticalAlign="middle" gap="12" paddingTop="10" paddingLeft="10">

    <s:Image source="{data.image}" height="170" width="170"/>

    <s:VGroup>
        <s:Label text="{data.name}"/>
        <s:Label text="{data.dOB}"/>
        <s:Label text="{data.sex}"/>
        <s:Label text="{data.birthplace}"/>
        <s:Label text="{data.colour} {data.ethnicity}"/>
        <s:Label text="{data.height}"/>
    </s:VGroup>

</s:HGroup>
```

Comment: What's the value of data.image?

Comment: its just a uri, for example:

C:\Users\pmcparlane\Adobe Flash Builder Burrito Preview\PersonSearch\images\default.jpg

Comment: Do you see it if you use a vertical layout instead?

Comment: Ye, well it displays fine when I drill down person to retrieve their details. see edit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think MobileIconItemRenderer displays all elements in a horizontal layout. If you want to display an image on top of the text, you have to create your own renderer or extends MobileIconItemRender and change the way it layouts its elements

Comment: +1 Yes, which is not as easy as you would hope, unfortunately.  MobileIconItemRenderer is an ActionScript-only class.  It adds all of the children and handles updates directly in AS3 as opposed to using MXML and skinning.  This is done for the purposes of efficiency.  You can always create a standard MXML ItemRenderer, but you will be giving up perf.  I've extended MobileItemRenderer before, though, so it can be done.  I actually recommend extending MobileItemRenderer because it is more simple to extend, and use the code from MobileIconItemRenderer as a guide.