# Custom List Design - Adobe Flex

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, adobe, mxml

Been struggling with a Person Search application in Adobe Flex for the **Blackberry Playbook** over the last few days. Basically I have the following:

**Main App with MXML Interface at Bottom**

```
private var persons:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();

public function init():void{    
            
   var p1:PersonSummary = new PersonSummary("Joe Smith", "9/9/1987", "img1.jpg");
   var p2:PersonSummary = new PersonSummary("Ben Smith", "9/5/1987", "img2.jpg");
   var p3:PersonSummary = new PersonSummary("John Doe", "9/9/1967", "img3.jpg");

   persons.add(p1); 
   persons.add(p2);
   persons.add(p3);
}
```

**PersonSummary**

```
class PersonSummary{

   private var name:String;
   private var dob:String;
   private var image:String;

   public function PersonSummary(n:String,d:String,i:String){
          this.name = n;
          this.dob = d;
          this.image = i;
   }
...
}
```

The interface I'm looking for:

[image]

What is the MXML? Ill forever be in the debt of anyone that can solve this problem for me!

Thanks
Phil

Comment: possible duplicate of [Images in Adobe Flex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5498789/images-in-adobe-flex)

Comment: sorry but this is clearly a duplicate of : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5498789/images-in-adobe-flex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A hint to get you on the right lines would be to use an ItemRenderer mxml, which has the details of what you want eg. image display, Name, DOB. You can build that in the interface builder.

Secondly you need a second mxml, which declares a VBOX with a List inside, the list should then bind to your ArrayCollection and each item will be picked up in the item renderer you built for each item in the list.

Sorry it's not a coded example.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:ItemRenderer xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
    autoDrawBackground="true">
 <s:VGroup width="600">
  <s:Image source="{data.imageURI}"/>
  <s:Label text="{data.dob}"/>
  <s:Label text="{data.name}"/>

 </s:VGroup>

 
</s:ItemRenderer>